# Problemas com javascript em aplicações ASP.Net MVC - Minification failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Acabei de upar meu sistema no servidor, e assim fui fazer os primeiros teste e esta acorrendo os seguintes erros em meus scripts Javascript

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '$'
(1,2): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '('
(1,11): run-time error CSS1031: Expected selector, found ')'
(1,11): run-time error CSS1025: Expected comma or open brace, found ')'
(53,2): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ')'
 */
```

Realizei às seguintes configurações no arquivo BundleConfig.cs em;

**SCRIPTS PERSONALIZADOS**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        /*############################################
         *############################################
         *S C R I P T S   P E R S O N A L I Z A D O S
         *############################################
        ##############################################*/
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Personal/lote-newlot").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/lote.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Personal/lote-index").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/p-lote-index.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Personal/sequencia").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/p-sequencia.js"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está minificando os arquivos Javascript com StyleBundle. Utilize ScriptBundle para arquivos Javascript